# How to scale SVG path to fit the window size?

Tags: css, svg

I am having troubles to scale the SVG to fit the window size.

In this example, I have a wavy path and a text element, what I want to achieve here is to move the text element along the wavy path from left to right (which is done by GSAP) and stop in the half way of the path in the initial load; it will move to the end when users start scrolling.

My problem is that, the wavy path created by SVG is too long, even the half way of the path will be off the window, I tried to scale down the wavy path by using `viewBox`, failed; using css `width: 100vw`, failed.

I also used the css `transform` property, it did scale the wavy path down, but that was a fixed size, I want to make it as responsive as possible, which means regardless the window width, the text element always stops in the middle of the screen first ( half way of the wavy path ), then moves to the right hand side of the screen. Is this possible when using inline SVG element? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

(Please view the example in full page mode, that will explain my problem perfectly, but the scroll function will be disabled because the height in that mode is `100vh`, there is no room for scrolling)

```js
document.getElementById("MyPath").setAttribute("d", document.getElementById("Path").getAttribute("d"));
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 0,
  delay: 1
});
tl.to("#Text", 3, {
  attr: {
    startOffset: '50%',
    opacity: 1
  }
});


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  tl.to("#Text", 3, {
    attr: {
      startOffset: '100%',
      opacity: 0
    }
  });
}, true);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<svg xml:space="preserve">
<defs><path id="MyPath"/></defs>
<path id="Path" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,188.2c186.2,84,261.8,84.9,440,66.4s295.2-130,535.2-129.4c240,0.6,357,144.3,591.1,144.3
 s450.1-141.2,651.1-141.2c271.7,0,354.2,141.2,612.1,141.2c240,0,423-141.2,669.1-141.2c119.1,0,202.3,33.8,281,68.7"/>
<text font-size="7em" >
  <textPath id="Text" fill='#88CE02' font-family=Oswald xlink:href="#MyPath" opacity=0 startOffset="0%" letter-spacing="5px">Love the little things.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your SVG to scale to fit the screen (or any parent container), it needs to have a `viewBox` attribute.  This attribute tells the browser the dimensions of the SVG content. Without it, the browser has know way of knowing how much it needs to be scaled.

Your path is about 3780 width, and the bottom of it is at y=144.  So a reasonable value of `viewBox` would be:

```
viewBox="0 0 3780 150"
```

```js
document.getElementById("MyPath").setAttribute("d", document.getElementById("Path").getAttribute("d"));
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 0,
  delay: 1
});
tl.to("#Text", 3, {
  attr: {
    startOffset: '50%',
    opacity: 1
  }
});


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  tl.to("#Text", 3, {
    attr: {
      startOffset: '100%',
      opacity: 0
    }
  });
}, true);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 3780 150" xml:space="preserve">
<defs><path id="MyPath"/></defs>
<path id="Path" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,188.2c186.2,84,261.8,84.9,440,66.4s295.2-130,535.2-129.4c240,0.6,357,144.3,591.1,144.3
 s450.1-141.2,651.1-141.2c271.7,0,354.2,141.2,612.1,141.2c240,0,423-141.2,669.1-141.2c119.1,0,202.3,33.8,281,68.7"/>
<text font-size="7em" >
  <textPath id="Text" fill='#88CE02' font-family=Oswald xlink:href="#MyPath" opacity=0 startOffset="0%" letter-spacing="5px">Love the little things.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried to use viewBox to solve this problem, but I didn't fully understand its usage and apparently I used it in a wrong way. Thank you.

Comment: First time I've almost understood what viewBox does - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do: add a media query defining the desired width and then apply the following styles separately for the `text` and `path` elements inside the svg element:

```
text {
  font-size: 2em;
}  

path {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(.3);
  transform: scale(.3);
}
```

See the snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById("MyPath").setAttribute("d", document.getElementById("Path").getAttribute("d"));
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 0,
  delay: 1
});
tl.to("#Text", 3, {
  attr: {
    startOffset: '50%',
    opacity: 1
  }
});


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  tl.to("#Text", 3, {
    attr: {
      startOffset: '100%',
      opacity: 0
    }
  });
}, true);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  text {
    font-size: 2em;
  }  
  
  path {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(.3);
    transform: scale(.3);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/plugins/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<svg xml:space="preserve">
<defs><path id="MyPath"/></defs>
<path id="Path" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,188.2c186.2,84,261.8,84.9,440,66.4s295.2-130,535.2-129.4c240,0.6,357,144.3,591.1,144.3
 s450.1-141.2,651.1-141.2c271.7,0,354.2,141.2,612.1,141.2c240,0,423-141.2,669.1-141.2c119.1,0,202.3,33.8,281,68.7"/>
<text font-size="7em" >
  <textPath id="Text" fill='#88CE02' font-family=Oswald xlink:href="#MyPath" opacity=0 startOffset="0%" letter-spacing="5px">Love the little things.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Ideally, I want to avoid using this method because `transform: scale()` will return a fixed size, which is not flexible enough to adapt to different screen sizes. What I am looking for is something like `width: 100vw` for inline SVG element, I only have a very limited knowledge about inline SVG so I don't know if that is something achievable.

Comment: Sure He Wang, I've also been seeking for this myself. I thought the only way to achieve it when using inline SVG was through modifying values in the media queries. @Paul LeBeau's solution is great, he solved it, thanks!