# Resizing path-based SVG to fit the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the height and width of the `svg`. I looked at [How to scale SVG path  to fit the window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930593/how-to-scale-svg-path-to-fit-the-window-size), which helps but is still not perfect. The svg is overflowing the screen. I would like it to be centered and not extend past the viewport. Here is my css:

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: visible;      
}
```

The svg, with a height and width of 400 and 300, looks like:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <path d="m..."></path>
    <path d="m..."></path>
</svg>
```

I'm setting the viewbox x and y to the height and width of the svg, and the `svg` is in an outer `relative` container. I would like it not to extend past the bounds of the outer container. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally switched up the height and width in the `viewBox`. Once I put the right values in, it was properly resizing to the height and width of the viewport.

```
<svg viewBox="min-x min-y x y">
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Change `viewBox` back to the original values and set `width="400"` and `height="300"`. They'll scale your SVG to the desired size :)

---

**Explanation:** The `viewBox` serve as a reference for the path descriptions. If a path goes from `0,0` to `1000,1000` and you change the view box to `0 0 400 400` the path will overflow the view box.

`width` and `height` are independent of the paths, they'll always scale the element.

Comment: When I explicitly set the height and width, the SVG did not scale - it remained at exactly 300 x 400 pixels. Utilizing the `viewBox` properly allowed my SVG to scale. Thanks for your help.